# How to receive Broadcast on PowerButton

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications

I am making an app in which if power key is pressed twice,The app will perform some task.Please provide me some help.I have made it but its not working.
I am including my class files here,Please correct me if I am going into wrong direction.

[Broadcaster](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxT4Sf_ySmmMVVdsTnV2czJKTUE/edit?usp=sharing)

[Listener](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxT4Sf_ySmmMWXI0VWlzdVRWLWc/editusp=sharing)

I don't know how to insert code here it is giving some error so I included links here.I am sorry for that.Please help me.

Comment: do you want to know how to type the double-click listener ?

Comment: yes.Pressing the power Key Twice

Answer (score 0):

Android recommends avoiding double clicks and using the long-click besides the normal click.
For the long click use this :

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
    // Do something here...
    return true;
}
return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
}
```

You also need to add this to the manifest

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PREVENT_POWER_KEY" />
```

If this doesnt work properly onKeyDown 
But I have never actually used this.

My personal opinion though is that you shouldn't hook the power key if you are planning to publish your app because unless it is doing something really an app shouldn't prevent the user from closing the screen

Comment: pity. can you explain in a few words in your question what is your app supposed to do ?

Comment: it will work like this.If somebody is going on a bike and unfortunately get an accident then he or she is not able to launch the application or may be he/she will not be able to get the phone but just in case if its possible person can double press the power but or long press as u said.and when power button is pressed the location and emergency message will be sent to the trusted person so that he/she can be helped.So I need a background service running all the time listening to power key so that it can handle it properly

Comment: @Kme I had a similar idea. You have a good idea but hooking such a function to the power button might trigger it accidentally. What I would do is to add a small widget with an emergency icon. Then the user should press the widget for sending his sos. Also consider adding a timed dialog so that for a time like 10 seconds the user will be able to cancel the sos if it is pressed by accident.

Comment: But the Hardware keys works in all conditions and fastly without any interuption like somebody may put his phone pattern locked and its not the time to unlock the phone but user should be helped as soon as possible.So i am asking for this particular power button...if any solution available.

Comment: @Kme I get what you mean. If the previous code doesnt work I dont think you can use the power button in android in general. The power button is faster to press but it can cause a lot of unwanted results .

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by receiving broadcast on ACTION_SCREEN_ON/OFF.
When the power button is pressed screen turns on/off depending on the fact whether screen is on or off at the time when pressing the power button.
I used this facility and put the logic in code such that if the user presses power button more than 5 times an sms will be sent to the trusted contacts.